# Is there a limit to a player's hand size in Summoner Wars?

Tags: summoner-wars

May a player have more than 5 cards in his hand at any time? This may happen when a card allows you to draw cards instead of attacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no hand limit size listed in [the rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/SW_Rulebook.pdf), but remember that you will not draw cards at the start of your turn.

> **Phase 1: Draw** - Draw cards until you have 5 cards in your hand (Example: if you start your turn with 3 cards in your hand you will draw 2 cards). If your Draw Pile is empty, you can no longer draw cards and must finish the game with the remaining cards on the Battlefield (including the Magic Pile) and in your hand.